# flash form error - no method with the name 'submit'

Tags: flash, coldfusion, cfform

I am new to ColdFusion and I am struggling to figure out how to do some simple functions that I could do in MS Access easily.

I keep getting an error: no method with the name 'submit'. This error only occurs because of the form format is flash.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <html>
<cfparam name="form.state" default="">
<cfparam name="form.lastname" default="">

<!---Grid Source---> 
<cfquery name="getArtists" datasource="cfartgallery">
    SELECT A.*
    FROM ARTISTS A
    WHERE
        1=1
    AND STATE like <cfqueryparam value="%#form.state#%" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="255">
    AND LASTNAME like <cfqueryparam value="%#form.lastname#%" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="255">
    ORDER BY A.LASTNAME, A.FIRSTNAME
</cfquery>


<head>
</head>
<body style="padding:20px;">

<cfform action="TEST.cfm" method="post" format="flash">


<cfformgroup type="horizontal" style="backgroundAlpha:0;font-size:12;color:##000;">
    <cfformgroup type="vertical" width="100">

<!---Query for STATE--->
<cfquery name="getState" datasource="cfartgallery">
    SELECT A.STATE   
    FROM ARTISTS A
    WHERE
        1=1
        AND LASTNAME like <cfqueryparam value="%#form.lastname#%" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="255">
</cfquery>

<!---STATE Dropdown---> 
<cfselect name="state" query="getState" queryposition="below" 
    label="State:"
    value="STATE"
    display="STATE"  
    required="no"
    selected="#form.state#"
    onchange="submit();"
    style="backgroundAlpha:0;" width="125">
    <option></option>
</cfselect>


    </cfformgroup>
    <cfformgroup type="vertical" width="100">

<!---Query for LastName--->
<cfquery name="getLast" datasource="cfartgallery">
    SELECT A.LASTNAME   
    FROM ARTISTS A
    WHERE
        1=1
        AND STATE like <cfqueryparam value="%#form.state#%" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="255">
</cfquery>

<!---LastName Dropdown---> 
<cfselect name="lastname" query="getLast" queryposition="below" 
    label="Last Name:"  value="LASTNAME" display="LASTNAME"  
    selected="#form.lastname#"
    required="no" 
    onchange="submit();"
    style="backgroundAlpha:0;" width="125">
    <option></option>
</cfselect>

    <a href="TEST.cfm"><input type="button" value="Reset"></a>
    </cfformgroup>
    </cfformgroup>

     <cfformitem type="spacer" height="20"/>


<!---Grid---> 
        <cfgrid name="myGrid" query="getArtists" format="html">
            <cfgridcolumn name="ARTISTID" header="ARTISTID" width="75" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="FIRSTNAME" header="FIRSTNAME" width="100" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="LASTNAME" header="LASTNAME" width="75" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="ADDRESS" header="ADDRESS" width="100" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="CITY" header="CITY" width="125" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="STATE" header="STATE" width="125" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="POSTALCODE" header="POSTALCODE" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="EMAIL" header="EMAIL" width="125" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="PHONE" header="PHONE" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="FAX" header="FAX" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="THEPASSWORD" header="THEPASSWORD" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
         </cfgrid>

    </cfform>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, why not use html forms? Just curious if there was a reason you must use flash ..

Answer (score 1):

Dan brings up a good point, my original answer was based on an HTML form, not a Flash form.  So that original answer is not valid.  However, I did find that the Flash forms in ColdFusion use ActionScript, not JavaScript.  See the reference here [Using ActionScript in Flash forms](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10372-7ff0.html).  That page also mentions that the custom ActionScript functions available for all form controls to reset or submit a form are `resetForm()` and `submitForm()`.  So try changing your `onchange` event from `submit();` to `submitForm()` like this:

```
    onchange="submitForm()"
```

I don't know if the semi-colon is needed or not for ActionScript.

*** --- ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW FOR HISTORICAL PURPOSES --- ***

You did not say when you are getting the error "no method with the name 'submit'.".  Looking at the code that you supplied I am assuming you get the error when you select something from either the state or last name drop-down box of your form.  Are you trying to submit the form when either of these selections change?  If my assumptions are correct then you might try giving your form an `id` and then qualifying your submit statement.  Something like this:

Give your form an `id`

```
<cfform id="yourformid" action="TEST.cfm" method="post" format="flash">
```

Qualify your submit statements

```
<cfselect ...
    onchange="document.getElementById("yourformid").submit();"
```

Comment: Not sure really (I don't use flash forms). I was basing this on the error that they posted.  Some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: @DanBracuk I believe you are correct about the flash forms.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone the onchange="submitForm()" worked. @Miguel-F

Answer (score 1):

in this context does not generate an HTML form. Hence you can't use JavaScript/DOM

Note: everything inside of `<cfsavecontent>` is  ActionScript:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="astest">
if(_global.arrMembers == undefined) _global.arrMembers = data.dataProvider.slice(0);
    var arrMembers = _global.arrMembers;
var arrDisplay:Array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arrMembers.length; i++)
 {
    if(arrMembers[i].dept == myselect1.value || myselect1.value == 'All')
    {
        arrDisplay.push(arrMembers[i]);
    }
}
    data.dataProvider = arrDisplay;

</cfsavecontent>
```

Then later:

```
<cfselect ... onChange="#astest#">
```

Reference: 
http://www.asfusion.com/examples/item/filtering-records-on-a-cfform-grid

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
onchange="submit();"
```

would be

```
onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

if you had an html form.  I'm not sure about flash forms.

Comment: Just saw your answer after posting mine. We came to the same conclusion.